# Generating Professional Functional Diagrams

Tags: diagram

I have designed a nice breakout board that I would like to share with the community but I would like to make it look super professional.

How does the Functional Diagram below get generated?

I am sure this can be hand crafted but there are so many similar functional diagrams like these that I am convinced there might be a single app/designer/company that generates these.

[image]

Comment: This is an Christmas tree, not a "professional diagram".

Comment: In the eye of the unexperienced beholder, it's a professional diagram.

Comment: Programs like ilustrator, inkscape, etc come to mind.

Comment: Go easy, guys. It does look professionally done in that the use of colour is consistent, text and graphics aligned, it's legible and useful as a reference wall chart, etc. I agree with Joren that often these are done using graphics packages. Inkscape is worth a try and is free.

Comment: That's not a professional EE diagram.  It appears to be a hobbyists misconception of what professionals might use.  It's also very busy, not clear what it's trying to say, and looks like it would have to be deciphered to get that information anyway.  Perhaps a valid question would be I'm trying to convey xxxx about my spiffy new board.  What is the best way to show that?  In any case, the answer is not this.

Comment: @OlinLathrop The _complete_ diagram is a bit more informative [Nano pinout](https://jpralves.net/post/2016/11/15/arduino.html#pinout_4)